# Why EF core not compared DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

`((a.DateOfRecive == null || b.DateOfRecive == null) || a.DateOfRecive.Value.Month == DateTimeOffset.Now.Month)`
или 
`((a.DateOfRecive == null || b.DateOfRecive == null) || a.DateOfRecive.Value.Month == b.DateOfRecive.Value.Month)`

get this exception

```
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

EF core 3.1

Comment: Please, provide more code details. Especially, how you are getting a data?

Comment: In entity framework core 3.0 client evaluation fails (in 2.2 works) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: In order to work, you are forced to trasform your IEnumerable into a list ToList() (triggering evaluation) then apply the condition again dbset.Where(bla bla).ToList().Where(here add the filtering with client evaluation)